# JMH-Benchmark methods with string parameters

Tags: jmh

How do I benchmark methods in JMH that is having string parameters, coming from other class?.

```java
@Benchmark 
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.All)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1)
@Measurement(iterations = 2, time = 1)
public refType getOrAdd(String refTypeName)
{
   return nameClass.containsValue(refTypeName)
}
```

When I compile, I am getting the following error:
Method parameters should be either @State classes

Answer (score 1):

Think about it: how JMH is supposed to know with what values to call the `@Benchmark` method with? Whatever calls that `getOrAdd` method should feed it  with data, and the caller should be the `@Benchmark` then. Or, it should be something JMH knows about and initializes by itself, for example `@State` class bearing the parameters, as the compile error suggests.

It is hard to see what you want to accomplish without seeing the rest of the code. Please look up how to create MCVEs.